# optimized query mongo find

Tags: mongodb

I want to fetch all data from a collection. Since running just find({}) crashes the mongo container (the liveness probe seams to fail because k8s reboot the container), I ask myself if using skip/limit will be better in order to fragment fetch into multiple parts.

Is that query optimized?

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').find({}).skip(300000).limit(200000)
```

Mongo logs gives: planSummary: COLLSCAN. Is that normal? Index on _id should be used, isn't it?

Here is some logs while request is performed:

```
2019-05-05T15:27:48.383+0000 I COMMAND [conn7] command off.TrunkOff command: getMore { getMore: 19694089771, collection: "TrunkOff", batchSize: 1000, lsid: { id: UUID("02770ee3-0b54-4b38-9b8e-23063b514434") }, $db: "off" } originatingCommand: { find: "TrunkOff", filter: {}, skip: 350000, limit: 100000, returnKey: false, showRecordId: false, lsid: { id: UUID("02770ee3-0b54-4b38-9b8e-23063b514434") }, $db: "off" } planSummary: COLLSCAN cursorid:19694089771 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:1000 numYields:15 nreturned:1000 reslen:10290608 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 16 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 16 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 16 } } } storage:{ data: { bytesRead: 10311365, timeReadingMicros: 300059 } } protocol:op_query 315ms
2019-05-05T15:28:21.281+0000 I COMMAND [conn6] command off.TrunkOff command: getMore { getMore: 19694089771, collection: "TrunkOff", batchSize: 1000, lsid: { id: UUID("02770ee3-0b54-4b38-9b8e-23063b514434") }, $db: "off" } originatingCommand: { find: "TrunkOff", filter: {}, skip: 350000, limit: 100000, returnKey: false, showRecordId: false, lsid: { id: UUID("02770ee3-0b54-4b38-9b8e-23063b514434") }, $db: "off" } planSummary: COLLSCAN cursorid:19694089771 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:1000 numYields:20 nreturned:1000 reslen:11985643 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 21 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 21 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 21 } } } storage:{ data: { bytesRead: 12016653, timeReadingMicros: 414440 } } protocol:op_query 427ms
2019-05-05T15:30:19.713+0000 I COMMAND [conn6] command off.TrunkOff command: getMore { getMore: 19694089771, collection: "TrunkOff", batchSize: 1000, lsid: { id: UUID("02770ee3-0b54-4b38-9b8e-23063b514434") }, $db: "off" } originatingCommand: { find: "TrunkOff", filter: {}, skip: 350000, limit: 100000, returnKey: false, showRecordId: false, lsid: { id: UUID("02770ee3-0b54-4b38-9b8e-23063b514434") }, $db: "off" } planSummary: COLLSCAN cursorid:19694089771 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:1000 numYields:13 nreturned:1000 reslen:9986640 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 14 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 14 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 14 } } } storage:{ data: { bytesRead: 10017227, timeReadingMicros: 270095 } } protocol:op_query 287ms
2019-05-05T15:30:44.023+0000 I COMMAND [conn7] command off.TrunkOff command: getMore { getMore: 19694089771, collection: "TrunkOff", batchSize: 1000, lsid: { id: UUID("02770ee3-0b54-4b38-9b8e-23063b514434") }, $db: "off" } originatingCommand: { find: "TrunkOff", filter: {}, skip: 350000, limit: 100000, returnKey: false, showRecordId: false, lsid: { id: UUID("02770ee3-0b54-4b38-9b8e-23063b514434") }, $db: "off" } planSummary: COLLSCAN cursorid:19694089771 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:1000 numYields:9 nreturned:1000 reslen:9228715 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 10 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 10 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 10 } } } storage:{ data: { bytesRead: 9247329, timeReadingMicros: 102849 } } protocol:op_query 110ms
2019-05-05T15:31:14.048+0000 I COMMAND [conn6] command off.TrunkOff command: getMore { getMore: 19694089771, collection: "TrunkOff", batchSize: 1000, lsid: { id: UUID("02770ee3-0b54-4b38-9b8e-23063b514434") }, $db: "off" } originatingCommand: { find: "TrunkOff", filter: {}, skip: 350000, limit: 100000, returnKey: false, showRecordId: false, lsid: { id: UUID("02770ee3-0b54-4b38-9b8e-23063b514434") }, $db: "off" } planSummary: COLLSCAN cursorid:19694089771 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:1000 numYields:21 nreturned:1000 reslen:11922134 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 22 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 22 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 22 } } } storage:{ data: { bytesRead: 11958959, timeReadingMicros: 410002 } } protocol:op_query 428ms
```

What is a good way to traverse a collection from end to end?

Here is cpu/memory usage.
[image: cpu goes max]
[image: Virtual memory is Gb more than mapped memory]

Virtual memory is gbs upper than mapped memory. cacheSizeGb is 1.

Comment: What is the MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your "crashes the mongo container" comment and the specific version of MongoDB? I suspect your issue is related to detecting available RAM in your Docker deployment. As per the [MongoDB Production Notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/): `If you run mongod in a container (e.g. lxc, cgroups, Docker, etc.) that does not have access to all of the RAM available in a system, you must set storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB to a value less than the amount of RAM available in the container.` The default is 50% of (available RAM -1 GB).

Comment: Note: if you upgrade to MongoDB 4.0.9+ (or the upcoming 3.6.13 release when available), improved detection of available RAM within containers should no longer require manual adjustment of the `cacheSizeGB` setting.

Answer (score 0):

As per MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/) For commonly issued queries, create [indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/). If a query searches multiple fields, create a [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#index-type-compound). `Scanning an index is much faster than scanning a collection`. The indexes structures are smaller than the documents reference, and store references in order.

For Example :

If you have a posts collection containing blog posts, and if you regularly issue a query that sorts on the author_name field, then you can optimize the query by creating an index on the author_name field:

```
db.posts.createIndex( { author_name : 1 } )
```

Indexes also improve efficiency on queries that routinely sort on a given field.

If you regularly issue a query that sorts on the timestamp field, then you can optimize the query by creating an index on the timestamp field:

Creating this index:

```
db.posts.createIndex( { timestamp : 1 } )
```

Optimizes this query:

```
db.posts.find().sort( { timestamp : -1 } )
```

Because MongoDB can read indexes in both ascending and descending order, the direction of a single-key index does not matter.

Where Indexes support queries, update operations, and some phases of the [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline-operators-and-performance).

**Use Projections to Return Only Necessary Data**

When you need only a subset of fields from documents, you can achieve better performance by returning only the fields you need:

`For example`, if in your query to the posts collection, you need only the timestamp, title, author, and abstract fields, you would issue the following command:

```
db.posts.find( {}, { timestamp : 1 , title : 1 , author : 1 , abstract : 1} ).sort( { timestamp : -1 } )
```

If you want to Limit the Number of Documents to Return or to Set the Starting Point of the Result Set then use limit or skip method.

**Limit the Number of Documents to Return**

The [limit()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/#cursor.limit) method limits the number of documents in the result set. The following operation returns at most 5 documents in the [bios collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bios-example-collection/):

```
db.bios.find().limit( 5 )
```

**Set the Starting Point of the Result Set**

The  [skip()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/#cursor.skip) method controls the starting point of the results set. The following operation skips the first 5 documents in the  [bios collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bios-example-collection/) and returns all remaining documents:

```
db.bios.find().skip( 5 )
```

For more information on using projections, see  [Project Fields to Return from Query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#read-operations-projection).

Comment: Thanks you for your message, but it answer not my question.The request is find({}). I want all data from start to end, no filters. There is off course an index on the _id field, it's mandatory. But mongo is crashing. My question is, does skip/limit ok with millions documents.

Comment: @Slim,The **limit()** function in MongoDB is used to specify the maximum number of results to be returned.

Comment: @Slim,If you shall use both skip/limit statement in your query statement then you shall not fetch all data. Due to their behavior.

Comment: Off course. I add explanations